# Force redraw with CADisplayLink

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, eaglview, cadisplaylink

I'm currently using `CADisplayLink` to show an OpenGL animation which works great. Sometimes, however a parameter changes and I need to redraw the view immediately and can't wait until the next frame is requested by `CADisplayLink`. If I don't do that, I get one frame wrong which looks really bad in my case.

So, how can I force a redraw of an `EAGLView` without interfering with the `CADisplayLink` stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CADisplayLink is calling method drawFrame, for example, then just call drawFrame yourself when you need to. No reason you need to wait for CADisplayLink if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you're storing your data in your view rather than in a data object. You should be able to change your data at any time, and your view should update when its needed to display. Move the data to a model object, and have the `EAGLView` draw itself based on the data when requested from the `CADisplayLink` rather than redrawing itself when the data changes.